# Windows 7 RDPservices won't listen on 3389

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

A few office machines seem to have lost the ability to receive RDP connections.

Looking at two of the machines - nothing is listening on 3389, tested with: `netstat -ano | findstr 3389` and rdp-tcp isn't listed in `qwinsta`

Have tried the following to start 'Remote Desktop Services' listening on 3389 to no avail

- `sfc /scannow`
- `regsvr32 remotepg.dll`
- left work domain then disabled rdp / re-enabled rdp
- trying starting extra services that may have any impact
- disabling all firewalls/antivirus
- disabling ipv6 on the adapter
- re-installing network drivers
- checking if KB972260 was installed (it wasn't)
- copying TerminalServices reg keys from known working machine
- `reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSCo
  nnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`
- performed gpupdate and checked policies in rsop.msc

---

[image: rsop.msc showing enabled terminal services]

---

[image: rdp enabled and set to accept any version]

---

[image: rdp services started]
[image: rdp services dependencies]

Comment: Is there possibly a GPO on the domain that might be administratively disabling it?

Comment: added cropped picture from rsop.msc - policies are to enable rdp

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the security level of the rdp on both machines (the one you're connecting to and the one you're connecting from). If they are on different levels that can cause the issue you are having. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff458357.aspx

> "By default, Remote Desktop connections are encrypted at the highest level of security available (128-bit). However, some older versions of the Remote Desktop Connection client application do not support this high level of encryption."

Comment: both machines are set to allow connections from any version

Comment: oh ok. By "disabling all firewalls/antivirus" you mean on both machines right? Sorry, but I have to ask...

Comment: if the machine doesn't have a service listening locally on port 3389 then something is wrong with the service. at this point the external network doesn't come into it

Answer (score 2):

Did the machines get moved to a different OU before you removed them from the domain?  If the OU had RDP disabled, when you left the domain, the policy may have remained behind.  You might try rejoining the domain and ensuring RDP is enabled via group policy.

Comment: just tried a gpupdate to refresh the group policy (which is applied to many more machines which have working rdp services) and rebooted - still not working

Comment: Have you checked the event log on the non-listening machines for any errors?